# Razor Convert String to DateTimeOffset with long timezone

Tags: c#, datetime, razor, datetimeoffset

i have a database with dates like this, stored as a string:
    2014-07-14T09:13:01.492+02:00:00

I want to convert it just to Datetime like "DD - MM - YYYY, hh-mm-ss" but it failed if i try to convert my string first to a datetimeoffset and then to my favourite datetime format. It seems that it fails because of the last ":00" in my string. How can if fix this easily?

This is the original errormessage (German) "Die Zeichenfolge wurde nicht als gültiges DateTime erkannt."

It means, that my string is not a valid Date-Time format

So this is my code (just with an examplestring)

```
                @{
                    string str = "2014-07-14T09:13:01.492+02:00:00";
                    DateTimeOffset newDate= DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);
                }
```

Comment: Details of the 'failure'? What does the error say?

Comment: This has nothing to do with razor

Comment: @Vogel612 : Yes - it was my first idea. But i have over 800.000 Datasets with this "time" in the database

Comment: @Vogel612 database normalization is not the same thing as using the correct data type in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would be to normalize your database like Vogel mentioned, but since you can't, you could probably try doing it this way:

```
string str = "2014-07-14T09:13:01.492+02:00:00";
DateTime dtnew = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz:00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTimeOffset newDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dtnew, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Not the best way, but works for sure!